# how to find the peak(r,theta) from DFT spectrum in matlab?

Tags: matlab, fft, spectrum

[image]

Suppose i have a matrix M
I apply DFT on it and shift it to the centre

```
img_fft = fft2(double(M));
img_spec = abs(img_fft);
img_shift = fftshift(img_spec);
```

Then according to my question, how could I find the peak of the spectrum ,i.e. (u,v) of the peak? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to determine where in the image the maximum value occurs.  However, the question says to ignore the DC value, which will very likely be the largest component in your spectrum so far.  As such, what you should do is find the maximum value, which will should be the DC value currently, and set it to `NaN`.  Once you do this, the next maximum value is what you're searching for to answer the question.

As such, do this first:

```
idx = find(img_shift == max(img_shift(:)));
img_shift(idx) = NaN;
```

If you set the maximum value here to `NaN`, the next time you call `find`, it will disregard this location and skip this location when searching for the maximum value.  Now, call `find` again:

```
[u,v] = find(img_shift == max(img_shift(:)));
```

Here, `u` would be the horizontal location of your image while `v` would be the vertical position.  This should now properly return the maximum peak that is not the DC value.  However, this isn't with respect to the centre as you have shifted the image, so once you're done with the above, you need to do:

```
[rows, cols] = size(img_fft);

u = u - floor(rows/2);
v = v - floor(cols/2);
```

This will now shift the origin to the centre of the image so this should now find where the maximum peak is with respect to the centre of the image.

You can now use `u` and `v` to determine `r` and `theta` according to your question.  In other words:

```
r = sqrt(u^2 + v^2);
theta = atan2(v, u);
```

---

A small note according to your comment is that you are encountering two values that share the maximum.  This is because the spectrum is symmetric.  After you do `find`, you will get two answers.  As such, either answer will give you the right result.  You can either choose any one of the `r,theta` pairs, or you can modify your `find` statement so that it only returns **one** answer.  In other words, do this:

```
[u,v] = find(img_shift == max(img_shift(:)), 1);
```

Note the second parameter of `1` at the end.  This means only return one result.

Comment: OMG! you are genius! how can u learn so much matlab techniques!

Comment: what if both r and theta appear 2 values?
i find that one the my matrix appear that r and theta give 2X1 matrix results

Comment: @Iamrubbishinprogramming - ah yes.  That's because the spectrum is symmetric.  Choose any one of the `r` and `theta` pairs and it'll give you the right result. Therefore, `r(1)` and `theta(1)` will be one answer and `r(2)` and `theta(2)` is another answer.

Comment: oh that's what i guess! Thanks, adore @rayryeng

Comment: @Iamrubbishinprogramming - I have edited my answer.  Check it out if it helps!

Comment: that's really a lot and helpful. I hope I can learn half of what you have learned

Comment: @Iamrubbishinprogramming - Thanks :)  It actually just takes practice.  When you start using MATLAB (or any language really...), you start to remember useful functions or techniques that you will use often.  Also, answering questions on StackOverflow helps with the memory aspect too :)